# Qual a melhor forma de aproveitar os dados do banco para funções relacionadas ao conteúdo recuperado?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Quando eu preciso utilizar uma informação do banco de dados para mais de uma tarefa, qual a melhor solução pensando na orientação a objetos( ex:listar os produtos de um carrinho e realizar cálculos ):

1 - Criar um único método que já faz tudo( 1 acesso ao banco e 1 while )

```
// recupera a lista de produtos do banco
$lista_produtos = $carrinho->listar_produtos();

// percorre os produtos e realiza as tarefas necessarias
while($carrinho_produto = $lista_produtos)
{
    $valor_produto = $carrinho_produto ->valor * $carrinho_produto ->quantidade;

    $valor_frete += $valor_produto * $fator_frete;`insira o código aqui`

    $valor_total += $valor_produto;
}
```

2 - Criar 3 métodos e listar os produtos em cada um deles, consequentemente realizando mais acessos ao banco( 1 acesso ao banco por método e múltiplos while ).

```
$carrinho->calcular_preco();
$carrinho->calcular_frete();
$carrinho->calcular_valor_total();
```

3 - Recuperar a lista de produtos do banco, armazenar em um vetor, passar o vetor em todos os métodos( 1 acesso ao banco e múltiplos while )

```
$vetor_produtos = $carrinho->listar_produtos();
$carrinho->calcular_preco( $vetor_produtos );
$carrinho->calcular_frete( $vetor_produtos );
$carrinho->calcular_valor_total( $vetor_produtos );
```

Answer (score 0):

Math,

a melhor opção dentre as que você listou é a terceira, do ponto de vista da performance (consultas no banco de dados são custosas para o desempenho), da manutenibilidade (cada função executa uma tarefa, se um erro ocorrer ficará claro de onde ele vem e portanto ficará mais fácil de corrigir) e do ponto de vista de estilo também, considerando que seu código é muito mais legível.

Também é importante pensar se estes produtos serão alterados por uma única instância da sua aplicação, pois caso contrário você apesar de estar trabalhando com informações sem necessitar de uma consulta ao banco de dados possivelmente estará trabalhando com uma cópia dos dados que não está atualizada.

Espero ter ajudado.